# Simple python script not creating directories

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory

I'm running the below script from the command line on my Mac with this:

```
python directory-create.py mkdirs mydirname
```

and here's the script directory-create.py:

```
import os, sys
def mkdirs(newdir):
    os.makedirs('/Users/bob/PycharmProjects/server-scripts/test/' + newdir)
    os.rename('/Users/bob/PycharmProjects/server-scripts/test/' + newdir, '/Users/bob/PycharmProjects/server-scripts/test/www.' + newdir + '.com')
    print 'test output'
```

I run it and absolutely nothing happens.  No errors returned, my print statement doesn't print (it does print with a simple Hello World script though) and no dirs created.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define the function, but you don't actually call it.
Add one more line afterwards to actually call the function:

`mkdirs("my new dir")`

Edit: There appears to be a misunderstanding in your code: You're passing in the function you want to call as a command-line argument.

It seems that you want to create the directory with the name that's specified on the command line. I rewrote the code to do that:

The usage would be:
`python directory-create.py mydirname`

The full code would be:

```
import os
import sys

def mkdirs(newdir):
    os.makedirs('/Users/bob/PycharmProjects/server-scripts/test/' + newdir)
    os.rename('/Users/bob/PycharmProjects/server-scripts/test/' + newdir, '/Users/bob/PycharmProjects/server-scripts/test/www.' + newdir + '.com')
    print 'test output'

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "No directory name specified!"
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    dirname = sys.argv[1]
    mkdirs(dirname)
```

Comment: That was it!  Thanks!  Works perfectly now.